# Android problems with fragment and fragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i created a tab layout with swipeable views, and each tab is a fragment. so when i place a viewflipper i changed the tabs to fragment activity, so an error in the adapter class says cannot convert FollowerFragments() to fragment. any help?

Adapter class:

```
public Fragment getItem(int index) {


    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Followers fragment activity
        return new FollowersFragment();
    case 1:
        // Best fragment activity
        return new BestSellingFragment();
    case 2:
        // Hot fragment activity
        return new HotDealsFragment();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Followerfragment class :

```
public class FollowersFragment extends FragmentActivity {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_followers, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
ViewFlipper flipper;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Getting View Flipper from main.xml and assigning to flipper reference variable
    flipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    flipper.setAutoStart(true);
    flipper.setFlipInterval(500);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FollowersFragment` should extend `Fragment` not `FragmentActivity`.

Why? `FragmentActivity` is an `Activity` containing fragments but it is not a fragment itself, thus it can't be converted.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class FollowersFragment extends FragmentActivity {
```

it should extends `Fragment`, not `FragmentActivity`

a `FragmentActivity` is an `Activity` with support for `Loaders` and `Fragment`. For instance through the `FragmentActivity` you can access the `FramgentManager` or the `LoaderManager`. A Fragment represent the `UI` and it is hosted by the `FragmentActivity`

Comment: This answer, although succinct and correct, could really use some details. I'll +1 if you add some text briefly explaining the difference between `Activity` vs `FragmentActivity` vs `Fragment` and the nature of the support libraries etc.